# How can I speed up deployment to the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

It takes several minutes each time I try to deploy an app for debugging on the emulator. 
I have installed HAX and that made the start of each instance and the execution much faster. I haven't optimized my computer for running the emulator in any other way. 
And deployment is still painfully slow.

Is there any measures I should take to speed it up? Current OS are Win8 and Ubuntu 13.4

And I wan't to stress that the question is about speeding up deployment on an allready running instance of the emulator. The startup of the emulator itself sometimes is faster than the actual deployment of the app.

I have consulted a few threads on speeding up the execution of the app and startup of the emulator but nothing specifically concerns the deployment.

Comment: The main thing that I know affects the deployment time is package size. In most cases there isn't much you can do about it(you either need the resources or you don't), but if you have a large app, this is probably normal.

Comment: That might be the case. Im currently doing a project with some heavy bitmaps. But since the deployment time actualy varies a bit with just small changes in the code I have a hunch there is something else affecting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if that's an emulator issue, or just your apk is too heavy, but I'd recommend trying [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) just in case, generally is fast as hell compared with the default one.

Comment: At this moment, Genymotion is the best solution by far. We use it too, and it cant stop bringing us satisfactions

Comment: I also highly recommend using Genymotion for near instantaneous APK deployment. I probably save at least 10-15 minutes a day NOT waiting for APK deployment :)

Comment: That was the best Android development advice I have gotten the last year. Genymotion shortened my deployment time to seconds from minutes for the exactly same binaries. It also starts faster and runs smoother. And all the controls such as logcat seems to work from Eclipse. It has lightyears better gps and device rotation handling. Right now I feel like I should be a part of their sales team.

Comment: Wow!@ Just installed Genymotion, and it is REALLY fast! Deployment is instant! Very VERY nice!

Comment: Glad it helped. Still wondering when will google publish a decent emulator (maybe with `Android Studio 1.0`). In the meanwhile, I'm happy with genymotion :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page will help:
https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

> In order to make the Android emulator run faster and be more
>   responsive, you can configure it to take advantage of hardware
>   acceleration, using a combination of configuration options, specific
>   Android system images and hardware drivers.

Comment: They basically advice you to use HAX, which is good. But as I stated I have allready done that.

Answer (score 0):

### Maximizing avd speed: General Solution

This is how I made my emulator lightning fast.
I have an intel core i7 processor and 16gb of ram on my Lenovo Thinkpad t430.

---

### IGNORE STEP 1 if YOU HAVE AN AMD CPU.

**Step 1:** If you haven't already, install intel haxm for windows 8.1. Google how to do this, there is no point in me going into this in detail because it is already well documented. Make sure that haxm is working when you run the emulator.  Installing haxm increased the speed of my AVD by 12 times. (I allocated 10gb of ram to haxm when installing)

**Step 2:** Make sure your computer's power settings are set to MAXIMUM PERFORMANCE. This is very important and can double the speed of your AVD.

**Step 3:** Go into your task manager and end all unnecessary PROCESSES. i.e. ITunes Helper.  Close all programs besides eclipse as well.

**Step 4:** Run your emulator while you have task manager open to PROCESSES.  You should see "emulator" in the description.  Right click on "emulator" and set Priority to High. You can also right click on eclipse and set its priority to High as well.

**Step 5:** In the task manager, right click on emulator and click on "affinity" to "all processors"

Done! Your AVD is now lightning fast.

Comment: Note that the question is not about running speed of the emulator. It is about how fast the app gets deployed on the emulator.

Comment: @Einar My mistake, I should have read more carefully.  It was really early when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that worked for me :

-Enable Instant Run
 Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
 Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

-Enable offline mode 
Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.
 Check the Offline work checkbox.

-Enable configuration on demand
Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.
Check the Configure on demand checkbox.

-Create library modules
-Convert images to WebP https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/
-Disable PNG crunching

See more https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build