# How to increase speed of android emulator speed

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to increase speed of android emulator. It is extremely slow although 2048MB emulator ram(I got 16gb of ram). I have found some solutions but All solutions for Intel processors. I have Amd processor and I am using Windows 8.1 64bit edition. I installed all tools and extras in Android SDK manager but still extremly slow. Is there any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I speed up deployment to the android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991031/how-can-i-speed-up-deployment-to-the-android-emulator)

Comment: If I understand the question tight, then it us not just start, stop or deployment. The whole emulator runs extremely slow. I face the same problem with newer Android versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/).It is more faster than emulator.Also you can use [snapshots](https://www.virag.si/2012/10/speeding-up-android-emulator/) to skip first boot of emulator.

Comment: do not use the snapshots. use the host GPU.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for all Processors

This is how I made my emulator lightning fast.
I have an intel core i7 processor and 16gb of ram on my Lenovo Thinkpad t430.

---

### IGNORE STEP 1 if YOU HAVE AN AMD PROCESSOR!!

Step 1: If you haven't already, install intel haxm for windows 8.1. Google how to do this, there is no point in me going into this in detail because it is already well documented. Make sure that haxm is working when you run the emulator.  Installing haxm increased the speed of my AVD by 12 times. (I allocated 10gb of ram to haxm when installing)

Step 2: Make sure your computer's power settings are set to MAXIMUM PERFORMANCE. This is very important and can double the speed of your AVD.

Step 3: Go into your task manager and end all unnecessary PROCESSES. i.e. ITunes Helper.  Close all programs besides eclipse as well.

Step 4: Run your emulator while you have task manager open to PROCESSES.  You should see "emulator" in the description.  Right click on "emulator" and set Priority to High. You can also right click on eclipse and set its priority to High as well.

Step 5: In the task manager, right click on emulator and click on "affinity" to "all processors"

DONE!!  Your AVD is now lightning fast!